# Python program can not open executable after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, exe

I made a fairly simple program that opens an exe file. When I run it in VSCode it works fine, but when I use pyinstaller to convert the program to an exe then the program no longer opens the executable file.

```
import os, time

    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    pathname = os.path.join(dir, 'Updates')
    filename = os.path.join(dir, 'Updates','ProgramSetup.exe')
    time.sleep(0.5) 
    os.chdir(pathname)
    os.system(filename)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: make sure you place this executable file in the same location as the original python file, because `dir` is dependent on the path where the file is saved originally

Comment: I did that. It still didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message?

Comment: Nope. It just doesn't do anything. Cmd opens for a sec and then closes.

Comment: Make sure your spec file or pyinstaller command has console=True, and run the exe from the command line. Read the documentation for when things go wrong https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Comment: @yem run the file from the cmd so that you can read what comes written (if anything).

Comment: I got the following error: Failed to execute script

Comment: @yem while making the executable, add `--debug` in the command, Look for useful messages there

Comment: wait, you can add a debug feature? How do I do that? I just write ```--debug``` before the python code? How do I actually debug it once I add that to the code?